# Can you build a MySQL query to show not found results from the conditional

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out how to find the emails that do not exist in a table using the emails from the conditional.

I could create a table with these emails but that seems like overkill for what I need it for. 
What I am looking for is a query that would show me the conditional value and NULL as the user ID.

Is this possible?

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.mail    
FROM `users` u
WHERE u.mail IN (
    'alot@of',
    'emails@that',
    'ineed@tofind',
)
```

This works great at finding the emails and associating the user id. Now I need to identify which emails do not exist in the result. I am currently only using 56 emails and 6 do not appear in the list. I am trying to identify which emails are not found.

`NOT IN` won't work as I have over 40,000 users. I only want to identify the emails not found from my conditional. I have 56 emails and only 50 results. I need to identify the 6 not found (they may not even be in the table at all)

Let me attempt to clarify this a little more:
I am given a list of emails for supposed accounts in the system. I am trying to find the accounts from the given email. This part is fine. Now, the issue I am having, I was given 56 emails but only 50 were found. I need to identify which emails out of the 56 were not found. The emails are all thrown into the conditional. `NOT IN` won't work because it would return all user but the 50 that were found. (roughly 40,000) I just need to identify the emails from the conditional that were not found in the table.

Thanks for any insight or suggestions to do what I need.

Comment: Have you considered `NOT IN()`?

Comment: Whatever would we do without [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Comment: `NOT IN` will not work for my needs. I have over 40,000 users and I only want to know out of my conditional which is not found. In other words, I have 56 emails, I only get 50 results. I want to identify the 6 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the comments, `NOT IN` may be helpful. But there are also other ways. One of them is to left join your table with the result of your query and show only non-coincident rows:

```
select u.uid, u.mail
from users as u
     left join (
         select u.uid, u.mail 
         from users 
         where mail in ('alot@of','emails@that','ineed@tofind')
     ) as a on u.uid = a.uid
where a.uid is null;
```

Add the fields you need to the join (if `uid` is not enough)

---

So your question now becomes more complicated... you want to find all the E-Mails *in your condition* that are not found in your table.

As far as I know, there's not a simple SQL sentence that will give you that... but you can work with temp tables and get it. The solution implies:

1. Create a temporary table to hold the values you want to search (and add the appropriate indexes to it)
2. Insert the values you want to search
3. Execute a `select` query to find non-matching rows

So... let's do it:

```
-- 1. Create a temp table to hold the values
drop table if exists temp_search_values;
create temporary table temp_search_values (
    mail varchar(100),
    unique index idx_mail(mail) -- Don't allow duplicate values here
);

-- 2. Insert the search values
insert into temp_search_values (mail) values
('alot@of'),('emails@that'),('ineed@tofind');

-- 3. Execute the query
select a.*
from users as u
     left join temp_search_values as a on u.mail = a.mail
where u.mail is null;
```

Remember: Temporary tables are only visible to the connection that created them, and are deleted when the connection is closed or killed.

Comment: Thanks but this still isn't what I am trying to find. I updated my question to see if I better explained my problem. I basically and trying to find the 6 emails that were not found in my query. This should be due to them not even being in the table.

Comment: Your updated answer works. Just needed to change the execute query to work for my needs. Also, if anyone else is tying to copy and paste this code, you will need a semicolon at the end of the drop table statement.

Comment: @Jeremy Oops! Sorry for the typo... correcting right now

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do what you want without creating some additional items to track the emails. Basically, you're trying to get MySQL to tell you which items in the WHERE portion aren't found, but MySQL can only tell you about rows in a table.

You need to make a secondary table that stores the email addresses from your list, call it `list`. I would make it a single column table with just the emails. Then LEFT JOIN it against the `users` table and find where the uid is null.

```
SELECT u.uid, l.mail
FROM `list` l
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.mail=l.mail
WHERE u.uid IS NULL
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was trying to bypass but it seems it's the only option. Thanks

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to an answer to better help future users. Up voted this as I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a strange result. It's not true and it's not false. If you want to check for it, you have to look specifically.

```
SELECT u.uid, u.mail    
FROM `users` u
WHERE u.mail NOT IN (
    'alot@of',
    'emails@that',
    'ineed@tofind',
) and u.uid IS NULL
```

*** Oh, I see what you're getting at. This will work, although it's not pretty. ***

```
select * from 
(SELECT  'emails@that' as v
UNION SELECT 'alot@of' as v,
UNION SELECT 'ineed@tofind' as v
) as test
left join users on u.mail = test.v
where u.uid is null
```

Comment: I wanted NULL as the user_id as there is no user ID. `NOT IN`won't work as it's not what I am trying to do. That would return all users in the table that are not in my list. Exactly the opposite of what I want. I am just trying to identify the emails that were not found as they are not in the table at all.

Comment: Answer corrected - I misunderstood the question. Unfortunately, unions and selects are the only way to create multiple rows from a list.